# trying to deploy java applet using jnlp

Tags: java, deployment, applet, jnlp, next-generation-plugin

i am trying to deploy applet using jnlp

my jnlp file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.6" codebase="http://localhost:8080/docRuleTool/appletjars/" href="dynamictree-applet.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>dynamictree</title>
        <vendor>dynamic</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6" href="http://localhost:8080/docRuleTool/appletjars/" />
        <jar href="dynamictree.jar" main="true" />
        <jar href="prefuse.jar" main="true" />
    </resources>
    <applet-desc 
         name="dynamictree-applet"
         main-class="com.vaannila.utility.dynamicTreeApplet.class"
         width="1000"
         height="1000">
     </applet-desc>
     <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

my applet code :

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    var attributes = { id:'DynamicApplet', code:'jstojava.dynamicTreeApplet',} ;
    var parameters = {jnlp_href:'./appletjars/dynamictree-applet.jnlp'} ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
</script>
```

My javascript :

```
function showSelected(value){
alert("the value given from  "+value);  
DynamicApplet.dieasenameencode=value; 
}
```

Error i am getting:

```
execption: The application has requested a version of the JRE (version 1.6) that currently is not locally installed. Java Web Start is unable to automatically download and install the requested version. This JRE must be installed manually..
JNLPException[category: System Configuration : Exception: null : LaunchDesc: 
<jnlp spec="1.6" codebase="http://localhost:8080/docRuleTool/appletjars/" href="http://localhost:8080/docRuleTool/appletjars/dynamictree-applet.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>dynamictree</title>
    <vendor>dynamic</vendor>
    <homepage href="null"/>
  </information>
  <update check="background" policy="always"/>
  <resources>
    <java href="http://localhost:8080/docRuleTool/appletjars/" version="1.6"/>
    <jar href="http://localhost:8080/docRuleTool/appletjars/dynamictree.jar" download="eager" main="true"/>
    <jar href="http://localhost:8080/docRuleTool/appletjars/prefuse.jar" download="eager" main="true"/>
  </resources>
  <applet-desc name="dynamictree-applet" main-class="com.vaannila.utility.dynamicTreeApplet.class" documentbase="http://localhost:8080/docRuleTool/" width="1000" height="1000"/>
</jnlp> ]
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.downloadJREResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.loadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: JNLPException[category: System Configuration : Exception: null : LaunchDesc: 
<jnlp spec="1.6" codebase="http://localhost:8080/docRuleTool/appletjars/" href="http://localhost:8080/docRuleTool/appletjars/dynamictree-applet.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>dynamictree</title>
    <vendor>dynamic</vendor>
    <homepage href="null"/>
  </information>
  <update check="background" policy="always"/>
  <resources>
    <java href="http://localhost:8080/docRuleTool/appletjars/" version="1.6"/>
    <jar href="http://localhost:8080/docRuleTool/appletjars/dynamictree.jar" download="eager" main="true"/>
    <jar href="http://localhost:8080/docRuleTool/appletjars/prefuse.jar" download="eager" main="true"/>
  </resources>
  <applet-desc name="dynamictree-applet" main-class="com.vaannila.utility.dynamicTreeApplet.class" documentbase="http://localhost:8080/docRuleTool/" width="1000" height="1000"/>
</jnlp> ]
```

Comment: What's the version of your installed JRE/JDK? I guess it's not 1.6 -- maybe you can use `<j2se version="1.6+" ... />` (note the `+`) in your JNLP?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line:

```
<j2se version="1.6" href="http://localhost:8080/docRuleTool/appletjars/" />
```

Java Web Start will try to download Jre 1.6 from the url given in the href attribute. Corrected version given below:

```
<j2se version="1.6" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
```

Sample JNLP file can be found here: [Distribute your Swing application via Java Web Start](http://techmindviews.blogspot.com/2010/08/java-swing-web-start-jnlp.html)